# WPF Insert usb when high cpu will lost multi-touch

Tags: wpf

I use win7 or win10 to test that when I insert usb when high cpu that will make the WPF lost multi-touch.

The bug step is :

1. make the high cpu
2. run a wpf app
3. insert an usb

You may see the wpf lost multi-touch and I run the step 10 times that I meet it 3 times. But step 2 and 3 must run in short time.

The wpf lost multi-touch like I run the code [Disable the RealTimeStylus for WPF Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/disable-the-realtimestylus-for-wpf-applications) and when wpf lost multi-touch I find the tabletDevices.count is 0.

I try to use OnTabletAdded but it can't help. I try to use OnTabletRemoved and then OnTabletAdded but it can't help.

I get all the win message when running a wpf app that I can't find the `WM_TABLET_DELETED`. So that I don't think the wpf remove the TABLET.

We write a app to test it and open it to https://github.com/walterlv/ManipulationDemo.

Comment: I've reproduced this issue in my demo. When I insert and remove the USB RealSense camera during the demo application starting up, the application lost all touch events.